# How to convert reg_binary value in registry to datetime in c#.net?

Tags: c#, registry

I have an application which reads the `PatternFileDate` of Symantec from the registry which is of the type `REG_Binary`. I have got the value of `PatternFileDate` as a byte array from the registry.How can I get the data in date or string format ?

- Main key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
- Sub Key: `SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\AV`
- Value: `PatternFileDate`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can decode the value.

Example registry value:

> **28030a**

First two characters represent the year, next two are the month and the last two of them are the day of the month. Each number is represented as a hexadecimal value.

So, from our example:

- **Year**: `28` in decimal is `40`. This value is added to the starting year of `1970`. So `1970 + 40 = 2010`. The year is **2010**.
- **Month**: `03` in decimal is `3`. The month is zero-based, so this is fourth month, that is **April**. For example, December would be `0B`.
- **Day of month**: `0a` in decimal is `10`. The day of month is one-based, so the day of the month is the actual decimal value. In our case, the day of month is **10th**.

So the example value results in:

> **April 10th, 2010**

Comment: byte[] PatternDate = (byte[])(SubKey.GetValue("PatternFileDate")); YY = PatternDate[0].ToString("X"); MM =  PatternDate[1].ToString("X"); DD = PatternDate[2].ToString("X"); Year = Convert.ToString(1970 + int.Parse(YY,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)); Month = Convert.ToString(1 + int.Parse(MM, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)); Day = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(DD, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)); //Reg Value - 2A 08 04 - Expected date - 05/09/2012

Comment: It worked with code which I have posted itself. Thanks for your support.